# Excluding the positive lookahead from the capture group

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
<root>
  <path>/my/data</path>
  <paths>/global/data</paths>
</root>
```

and I'm trying to get a regex capture group for `/my/data/` and `/global/data` only. I tried this:

```
^\s*(?=<path>|<paths>)(.*)$
```

but I don't understand why the `(.*)` groups are:

`<path>/my/data</path>`
`<paths>/global/data</paths>`

Is there any way to exclude the positive lookahead from the capture group?

Comment: Because Lookaheads don't _consume_ anything. Use `^\s*<paths?>(.*)<\/paths?>$`. Or `^\s*<(paths?)>(.*)<\/\1>$` if you want to ensure the opening and closing tags match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` consumes the `<path>` and `<paths>` that are checked for with your lookahead. Look, `(?=<path>|<paths>)(.*)` in your regex first checks if there is `<path>` or `<paths>` immediately to the right of the current location and if there is, `(.*)` readily consumes (=adds the matched text to the overall match value and advances the regex index to the end of the current subpattern match) the `<path>` or `<paths>` since `.*` matches zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Make the lookahead pattern consuming:

```cs
^\s*(?:<path>|<paths>)(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8VJpSQ/1).

Or, remove the alternation and contract the pattern to:

```cs
^\s*<paths?>(.*)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8VJpSQ/2). Here, `<paths?>` matches `<path`, then an optional `s` char and then a `>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
(?:(?<=<path>)|(?<=<paths>))([^<]*)
```

`(?<` means *Lookbehind* and works in PCRE, Javascript, Java, Python, ...

[Regex101 Test](https://regex101.com/r/yRckmY/1/)

[image]